# Can anybody tell me in which scenarios Salesforce integration is required with Java?

Tags: integration

I am able to integrate sample applications but I can not understand the real time scenario where exactly we can go for integration with external applications. I have gone through integration patterns where I found one scenario like  'orders are managed by an external (remote) system that need to update the order status in salesforce as the order passes through its processing stages.' I would be very greatfull if some one could help on this as i am very interested on integrations in Salesforce.

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? Do you want to know more about scenarios or do you want to know more about how (technically) to integrate?

Comment: Thank you Andre Wille. I want to know  scenarios how external systems can be used in salesforce. I am able to understand the purpose of integration salesforce with SAP but confusing  what kind of benefit we get by integrating salesforce with java web applications and what is the cause forces companies go for salesforce integration with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one scenario i see quite often is for example a web shop is integrated with salesforce. The sales reps use salesforce as their crm and all the data from the shop gets synced to salesforce so that all data is in one place. Every order gets synced to salesforce and also the account data gets synced to contacts and accounts in salesforce.

On the other hand you can manage your products and pricing in salesforce and sync it to the shop. You then can use salesforce for your data analysis using the reporting engine, you can also use it for automated marketing and for generating quotes and invoices.

In that case developers can focus on building customer facing features and there is no need to build administrative interfaces and business people can do all their work in salesforce.